# Overlays and Frame Alignments

Tags: beamer, overlays

Can I have one frame whose alignment can be changed using overlays. I want something like this:

```
   \begin{frame}{[t<2>]}{Top alignment}
    This is the content of the slide. 
   \end{frame}
```

First slide to be center aligned and the second one top aligned, and so on. Is this possible in LaTeX Beamer?

Comment: Why not just specify them individually?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the vertical position of some text with `\vspace{}`. Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{Top alignment} 
\only<1>{\vspace{-5cm}}
\only<3>{\vspace{5cm}}
This is the content of the slide. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

You can also use `\vfill` before or after the text.